# Can I post edited comedy images of Indian politician in social website

Tags: india, indian-penal-code

I edited an image of an Indian politician. Added some comedy picture taken from a Tamil movie. And also wrote some thing funny about that politicians. Is that legal. Can I post that image to a social website.. Do I face any problem in future for posting such images. What does the law say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Legally you face no problem. The section 66A of the Indian IT Act, which used to be previously misused for penalizing anyone who dared insult a politician, has been struck down as unconstitutional by the Supreme Court of India.

But the police could still detain you for 48 hours (legally) without giving any grounds; they are required to do that, but the police are seldom held accountable.

The supporters of the said politician can vandalize your home and office without fear of legal action.

**I am not a lawyer. Whatever is posted above is my opinion and data that I believe to be true to the best of my knowledge and resources available to me. Please contact a lawyer for professional advice.**